# Looping through worksheets and pasting the last rows of each into a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all the worksheets in a workbook, find the last used row in each worksheet and paste that row in a new worksheet named `aggregate`. Problem is that it is overwriting the rows in worksheet `aggregate` while looping. I would like to copy last row of first worksheet, paste it it to aggregate. Next, copy last row of second worksheet and paste it to next ***empty*** row in `aggregate` worksheet and so on. My code for some reason is not incrementing the next "empty" row in `aggregate` worksheet.

Code:

```
Sub aggregate()
'
' aggregate Macro
'

'
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("aggregate")


For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Name <> "aggregate" Then

  With ws
    ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("aggregate").Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  End With
 End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

I have spent last two hours finding the problem but to no luck. Please help.

Comment: `If ws.Name <> "aggregate" Then` is a case-sensitive comparison. Is the worksheet's name actually lower case?

Comment: Yes, worksheet name is lower cased.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem here. Might it be that some rows in some of the worksheets have nothing in column A?

Comment: I thought the same thing @RonRosenfeld but then the .End(xlUp) would not capture that row, it would keep looking up (from the bottom) for the first non-blank cell in column A.

Comment: @Jeeped Agree. But I thought perhaps he was not expressing what he was seeing in a way I could understand.

Comment: Thank you so much for acknowledging the problem. @Jeeped I am still facing the problem. I am getting only the data from last worksheet in `aggregateIt` worksheet. It is for some reason not able to find next blank row in that worksheet.

Comment: re: *'I am getting only the data from last worksheet'* - do the other worksheets you want to copy data from have values in column A? If not then yes, you are going to repeatedly overwrite due to the blank cell in column A.

Comment: @Jeeped, I actually had blank values in column A. That was the problem. Thank you so much for helping me out. I am very novice with vba, hence wasn't able to figure out.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for pointing that out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your problem stems from some rows not having data in column A, then this macro, which uses the `.Find` method to determine the last row, should be useful:

```
Option Explicit
Sub aggregate()
'
' aggregate Macro
'

'
 Dim ws As Worksheet ', wksDest As Worksheet
 Dim wsDest As Worksheet
 Dim c As Range, d As Range


 Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("aggregate")


For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Name <> "aggregate" Then

  With ws
    Set c = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
         searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    With wsDest
            Set d = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
            If d Is Nothing Then Set d = .Cells(1, 1) 'check if wsDest is blank
    End With

    If Not c Is Nothing Then _
        c.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=d.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  End With
 End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not look like it should fail in the way you are describing. However, you seem to bounce in and out of methods; e.g. you `set` wksDest without declaring the variable and then never use it, you use a `With ws` block but do not use that either.

Here is a quick rewrite.

```
Sub aggregateIt()
'
' aggregate Macro
'
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet

    Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("aggregate")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wksDest.Name Then
            With ws
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy _
                  Destination:=wksDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I also renamed your sub procedure since **AGGREGATE** is a worksheet function.